# Prove the limits of type $\infty - \infty$.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, indeterminate-forms

Need an explanation for

$$\lim_{x\to y} \cot(g(y)-g(x))-g'(y)^{-1}\cot(y-x)=\frac{g''(y)}{2g'(y)^2}$$

This question does not have any additional conditions, clearly the functions $g$ is from $C^2$. The problem is, I am getting $\frac{g''(y)}{g'(y)^2}$ (using mean value theorem), but while I solve by substituting $g$ with some other functions, I get the answer of the form $\frac{g''(y)}{2g'(y)^2}$ (I used mathematica). What I don't understand is how that $\frac{1}{2}$ came over there. Here is my explanation: $\cot(g(y)-g(x))-g'(y)^{-1}\cot(y-x)=\frac{1}{y-x}\left(\frac{y-x}{g(y)-g(x)}(g(y)-g(x))\cot(g(y)-g(x))-g'(y)^{-1}(y-x)\cot(y-x)\right)$

as $x\to y$, $(g(y)-g(x))\cot(g(y)-g(x))$ and $(y-x)\cot(y-x)$ tends to 1. Hence, the total limit must tend to $\frac{d}{dy}\frac{1}{g'(y)}$. If there is any mistake in my explanation kindly point it out.

Comment: yes it is multiplicative inverse

Comment: Try to be a little more polite when asking a question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $z=x-y$, $A=g'(y)$ and $B=\frac{1}{2}g''(y)$, the limit can be rewritten, using
$$
g(y+z)=g(y)+g'(y)z+\frac{g''(y)}{2}z^2+o(z^2)
$$
as
$$
\lim_{z\to0}
\frac{\tan(Az+Bz^2+o(z^2))-A\tan z}
     {A\tan z\tan(Az+o(z))}=
\lim_{z\to0}
\frac{Az+Bz^2-Az+o(z^2)}{A^2z^2+o(z^2)}=\frac{B}{A^2}=\frac{g''(y)}{2g'(y)^2}
$$

Comment: @ShyamSunder Apparently you were missing the $\frac{1}{2!}$ in the Taylor polynomial. `;-)`